# Undefined variable $.parseJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My authenticate.php file is returning an object

```
Json: [{"u_id":"1","u_name":"Nabeel" }]
```

Here is my js:

```
success: function(result) {
  var obj=$.parseJSON(result);
  alert(result);      //[{"u_id":"1","u_name":"Nabeel" }]
  alert(obj.u_id);    //undefined
  window.location="#timeline";
}
```

I want to save u_id and name in a separate variables but I keep on getting undefined as a result.

I tried using the `jQuery.parseJSON` function as well but I was getting "undefined variable Jquery"

Comment: Shouldn't `result` already be parsed?

Comment: Fix php code to return an object instead of having outer array and set `dataType:'json'` so you don't have to do own parsing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your PHP script is returning an array so you need to provide the index or fix your PHP output.

```
console.log(obj[0].u_id);
```

Comment: or: `var obj = $.parseJSON(result)[0];`

Comment: Thanx mate :) u just saved me :)